# Is this line $|f(x,y)| = \Big| f(x,y_0) + \int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{\partial f}{ \partial y} (x,t) dt\Big|$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a real-valued function of two variables $(x,y)$ that is defined on the square $Q = \{(x,y)\,|\, 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ and is a measurable function of $x$ for each fixed value of $y.$ For each $(x,y) \in Q$ let the partial derivative $\partial f/ \partial y$ exist.

Assume that there exists $y_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x,y_0)$ is an integrable function of $x$ on $[0,1].$ For any $(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1],$ we have \begin{align*}
      |f(x,y)| = \Big| f(x,y_0) + \int_{y_0}^{y}  \frac{\partial f}{ \partial y} (x,t) dt\Big|     
  \end{align*}

Is my last line correct, am I allowed in Lebesgue integral to say this?If so, please let me know which theorems and propositions I should use to say this. Note that I am allowed to use until only section $4.4$ in Royden, real analysis, fourth edition.

Comment: The integral in your equation need not exist. You need more hypothesis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what more hypothesis do I need?

Comment: You need $\partial f /\partial y (x,t)$ to be integrable with respect to $t$. This holds for instance if $\partial f /\partial y$ is continuous.

Comment: @yes it is integrable as it is dominated by an integrable function.